# how use specify icon, label and link to app for determineAttributeKind on cascades

Tags: qt, native, blackberry-10

I`m developer blackberry and try create to new attribute under to contacts but not set knows determineattrib correctly.

Code:

```
ContactBuilder builder;

builder.addAttribute(ContactAttributeBuilder()
                            .setKind(AttributeKind::Name)
                            .setSubKind(AttributeSubKind::NameGiven)
                            .setValue("NAME_test"));
...

other attributes

...

      builder.addAttribute(ContactAttributeBuilder()
.setKind(ContactAttributeBuilder::determineAttributeKind("Attr_test"))
.setSubKind(ContactAttributeBuilder::determineAttributeSubKind("SubAttr_test"))
.setValue("1234567890"));

...
```

With other default attribute no problem.

I found a example:
https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Gmail-synchronization-removes-some-attributes-from-contacts/td-p/2676999

result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzh3s.png

The problem is that not show the attributes ("Attr_test" and "SubAttr_Test")names in the contact.

¿How adding a icon, label and link for app on attribute from the application?

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

A photo you add with:

```
ContactBuilder.addPhoto()
```

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__pim__contacts__contactbuilder.html#function-addphoto-photo-isprimary

A link to a website you could add with AttributeKind::Website.

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__pim__contacts__attributekind.html#enumvalue-website

I don't know what kind of label you want to add but you would have to use one of the AttributeKind::Type enum values to add a label.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but i agree a new attribute with  .. determineAttributeSubKind...  and I cant add icon or name to this attribute... An example is whatsapp ! on attributes add her icon and directly lauch the app.